# su user -l and su user -l -c "cmd" does not give the same result

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

I need to run command from `root` user but on `gameservice` user. 
Unfortunately, the `PATH` is not hydrated with `NVM` bin directory and thus, `node` is not a command.

I've managed to make it working by export the `PATH` directly in the command like this but it's ugly.

`su gameservice -l -c "export PATH='$PATH:/home/gameservice/.nvm/versions/node/v13.7.0/bin/' && cd universalgame-server && ./node_modules/.bin/babel src -d dist --source-maps"`

But when I try to play with stuff, I can prove that both my `.profile` and my `.bashrc` files are executed.

If I just log in as the user from `root` with `su gameservice -l` and `echo $PATH`, I have the nvm bin dir inside.

I think I'm just missing some basic knowledges of how bash is working, can someone spot my error please ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `bash` is invoked as a non-interactive shell. According to the `bash` man page:

> An interactive shell is one started without non-option arguments
>   (unless -s is specified) and without the -c option  whose  standard input
>   and error are both connected to terminals (as determined by isatty(3)),
>   or one started with the -i option.  PS1 is set
>   and $- includes i if bash is interactive, allowing a shell script or a
>   startup file to test this state.

In Ubuntu, the default `.bashrc` starts with these lines:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

so `.bashrc` does get executed, but decides to exit right away. If you remove those lines, the `PATH` variable will be set to what is in the `.bashrc` file and you will be able to run the `node` command.

A better approach, in my opinion, is to write a script in which you set up all the necessary environment, and run the command you need, then execute that script in the name of the user. This will work no matter what, and you won't be dependent in any startup files in the user's directory.